# React props syntax with ES6 spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I noticed the following in a React app:

```
<UserList
  {...{ userIdsTyping, users }}
/>
```

What exactly is `{...{ userIdsTyping, users }}` doing here? I understand it's passing children to the UserList component, but how does the spread operator work here? What interaction does it have with `userIdsTyping` and `users`?

Comment: Can you show more complete context for this code or is this not actually Javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spread operator "expands" the object inline. It's equivalent to the following syntax:

```
<UserList
    userIdsTyping={userIdsTyping}
    users={users}
/>
```

The object itself `{ userIdsTyping, users }` is [ES6 shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), and expands to `{userIdsTyping: userIdsTyping, users: users}`.

This assumes values for `userIdsTyping` and `users` are defined somewhere else within scope.